# Best way to update Ruby to the latest 1.9 version on OS X?

Tags: ruby, macos

Does Mac OS X support ruby version 1.9.+? Is it recommended to update to 1.9 or should I wait?

The reason I ask is because I'm trying to use some plugins that only support Ruby 1.9+

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most people use [RVM](https://rvm.io) to install Ruby on the mac. Basically it allows you to have multiple versions of ruby installed on the same machine and to switch between them at will. You can also install gems on a project by project basis rather than installing them all globally using sudo like you probably do now.

You can install RVM by running

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.ioinstall/rvm)
```

in terminal (assuming you have git installed). Full installation instructions can be found on the [RVM site](https://rvm.iorvm/install/).

[Here](http://sirupsen.com/get-started-right-with-rvm/) is a tutorial which I personally found invaluable when getting used to using RVM in my workflow at the start. It will probably help you too.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to update the system Ruby, since OS X uses it for some stuff (I think). Instead, use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).

Comment: "since OS X uses it for some stuff (I think)", yes it does. I've been harping on this for months. Try `find /usr -name '*.rb'` to see. Add `sudo` to that to see at least one more file.

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend a "preferred" method, but just outline the possibilities:

1. Install ruby 1.9 from ports using `port install ruby19 +nosuffix`
2. Install using RVM as others suggested
3. Check out the stable version with svn, then

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/ruby --enable-shared
make && sudo make install
```

I prefer the third way, as it gives the most flexibility, and the latest stable version. Don't forget to add /opt/ruby/bin to path before everything else if you choose this path (no pun intended).

And as others said - don't touch the system ruby, Mac OS X depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/).
It can be installed along with regular Ruby as the commands of MacRuby begins with "mac", so, irb is macirb and ruby is macruby.

Having both installed, you can choose which one use in each moment by prefixing the "mac" string or not

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave the system Ruby alone. Most people would just use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) to install 1.9, but [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) also has Ruby 1.9.2 available.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Homebrew to install it (into /usr/local).